# Resolve Sed label Too Long Solaris

Tags: sed, solaris

When running this i am getting `solaris Label too long :L; $ {s/\n//g   ....`
Kindly, please help me to resove this issue. I am a new bee to this

```
sed ':L; $ {s/\n//g;
        s/<\/test1>/\n/g
        s/<test>\|<tag.>.*<\/tag.>//g
        s/\n$//}
  N; bL
```

Comment: You can probably solve this by inserting a newline instead of a semicolon after the label, or separating the command into two (`sed -e ':L' -e '${s/\n//g;...'`), but you should use an HTML parser instead in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Benjamin. I applied your suggestion, Now i am getting Sed :command Grabled s/\n$// .  Please help